# generate routes for one page landing pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am attempting to build a simple webpage using Rails and this guide to great looking landing pages by William Ghelfi (thanks!) http://www.williamghelfi.com/blog/2013/08/04/bootstrap-in-practice-a-landing-page/

I have started a new project on rails using Rails 4.0.0

Server is running fine on localhost:3000 as evidenced by the RoR landing page.

My question is what's the best way to generate routes and controllers for a one page landing page using RoR?

Right now, when I attempt to point to localhost:3000/lpd.html I get the error No route matches [GET] "/lpd.html" No routes defined.

Comment: have you built a RoR app before?

Comment: Since you will only have a SPA (single page application) you probably just want to use your application_controller.rb and views/layouts/application.html.erb.

Comment: Yes, I've built a few, but from step by step guides online.

Comment: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-static_pages- Cheers.,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want a static page, you can just move the `lpd.html` to the `public` folder and it will work. But many rails websites have semi static pages.

So you could create a `LandingController` or `HomeController` where you keep all your semi-static pages. E.g. home, about, contact us ...

So for instance, do the following

```
rails g controller Home index about
```

This will generate a `HomeController` with two actions `index` and `about`, with the corresponding views and default routing. So in `app/views/home` two views will be added, 
which you can then edit as you wish.

Then you can edit the routing (in `config/routes.rb`) as follows:

```
get '/about' => 'home#about'
root_to 'home#index'
```

This will make sure that `http://localhost:3000` will be your `home/index` view, and `http://localhost:3000/about` will be your about page.